# Скачивание файла из яндекс диска(гугл-диска) по имени

Tags: python, google-drive, яндекс-диск

в папку на яндекс диск или гугл диск приходит файл, имя которого я знаю. Пожскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность с помощью python скачать данный файл по имени? Я находи в интернете титориалы, но они использовали ссылку на файл для скачивания.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/ а документацию смотрели?

Answer (score 0):

Не так давно мне нужно было получать список всех файлов, которые есть в папке на я.диске и, если файла нет в подготовленном списке, то выкачивать его себе.
Имя файла в итоге я проверил следующим образом:

```
import requests as r
import urllib.request
import json

adr = r.get('https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources?public_key=ссылка_на_диск').json()

for now in adr['_embedded']['items']:
    destination = rf'путь_к_файлу\{now["name"]}'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(now['file'], destination)
```

Имя файла я получил в цикле: now['name']. Дальше все просто, если у Вас имя файла совпадет с тем, который Вам необходим, то выкачиваете его через ссылку now['file'], если нет, то просто пропускаете.